# Control dynamic Custom Control Properties from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple UserControl in ASP.NET (VB) with the following code pages:

**ASCX:**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="DistPOLine.ascx.vb" Inherits="DistPOLine" %>

<asp:Label ID="lbDistSKU" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**ASCX.VB**

```
Partial Class DistPOLine
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Property DistSKU As String
        Get
            DistSKU = lbDistSKU.Text
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            lbDistSKU.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

If I reference the control directly in an aspx page, I can set its DistSKU property without a problem.

```
<%@ Register src="DistPOLine.ascx" tagname="POline" tagprefix="POL" %>
<POL:POline ID="POline1" DistSKu="test Here" runat="server" /><br />
```

But in my code behind, where I create the user controls within a loop, I can't access the property directly, even by using FindControl and casting the control as a label. The controls get created, but I need to manipulate them after creation. (I've simplified the control and the code so only one property remains)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Globals
Imports Approver
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class OrderEntry_Entry
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        Dim custPOLine As UserControl, lLoop As Long

            for lLoop=1 to 5
                custPOLine = Page.LoadControl("~/DistPOLine.ascx")
                custPOLine.ID = "poLine" & Format(lLoop + 1, "000")
                Me.plPOLines.Controls.Add(custPOLine)

                'ctrlLabel = Me.FindControl("poLine" & Format(lLoop + 1, "000") & "_lbDistSKU") 'This is not working
                'ctrlLabel.Text = dr("CustSKU").ToString

            next

    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the property of your user control, you should declare your user control as the type of your custom user control.

```
Dim custPOLine As DistPOLine

custPOLine.DistSKU = "YourString"
```

And if you did want to find the control and edit the label that way, you should just be able to do a find control on the user control you created rather than the page you are adding them to.

```
Dim lbl As Label = custPOLine.FindControl("lbDistSKU")
lbl.Text = "YourString"
```

Comment: Thanks j.f. Solution 2 works perfectly to access the inner controls. For solution 1, how do I go about adding the control to the page. If I try `custPOLine = CType(Page.LoadControl("~/DistPOLine.ascx"), DistPOLine)`, I get an error on the conversion from Control to DistPOLine.

Comment: Good to hear. Try without the conversion. `custPOLine = Page.LoadControl("~/DistPOLine.ascx")`.

Comment: Without the explicit conversion the error message is exactly the same: `Value of type 'system.web.ui.control' cannot be converted to 'distPoLine'`

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure. I can't seem to reproduce the same error. It is working just fine for me.